# How to print table data in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

in My Larvel 5.6 app I am working with mysql db. and in my application I have vehicle table with following columns,
vehicles,

```
id  category  number  brand model
1   car       123     bmw   520d
2   van       258     ford  mark
3   car       256     benz  ultra
4   car       259     bmw   520d
etc
```

and I am going to group all models of the table and printing here as My controller,

```
public function modelstatic()
{
      $models = Vehicle::groupBy('modelname')->select('id', 'modelname', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();  
      return view('modelreports.modelstatic')->withModels($models);
}
```

my printing blade file is this,

```
@foreach($models as $model)
     {{ $model->modelname }}
@endforeach
```

it is printing well as

```
520d
mark
ultra
```

now I need print in-front of model name there brand name as

```
520d - bmw
mark - ford
ultra - benz
```

Then how can I do this now? I have separate Models for brand and model and still there are not relationship between Models. how can I do this, may I need relationship or may I could print brand name via vehicle table data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you select the model name column, you must also select the brand column, and then print the model with his brand name.

Try this:

In your controller:

```
public function modelstatic(){
      $models = Vehicle::groupBy('modelname')->select('id', 'modelname', 'brand', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();  
      return view('modelreports.modelstatic')->withModels($models);
}
```

and in your view:

```
@foreach($models as $model)
     {{ $model->modelname }} - {{ $model->brand }}
@endforeach
```